# how to use backward relation in django tastypie

Tags: django, reverse, tastypie

this is my model

```
class Nisit(models.Model):
```

and this

```
class Page(models.Model):
followingNisit = models.ManyToManyField(Nisit,blank=True)
```

this is my resource

```
class NisitResource(ModelResource):
    page = fields.ToManyField('chula.api.PageResource','page_set',null=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Nisit.objects.all()      
    resource_name = 'nisit'
    filtering = {
        'page' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        'id' : ALL,
    }

class PageResource(ModelResource):
    followingNisit = fields.ToManyField(NisitResource, 'followingNisit',null=True)
    reporter = fields.ManyToManyField(ReporterResource,'reporter')
    followers_count = fields.CharField(attribute='followers_count')

class Meta:
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'page'
    authorization= Authorization()
    filtering = {
        'id':ALL,
        'followingNisit': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
    }
```

It's ok when I request -------127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/page/?format=json&followingNisit__id=1

But In the opposite way ,when i request ---------127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/nisit/?format=json&page__id=1, I will get this error

```
{"error_message": "Cannot resolve keyword 'page_set' into field. Choices are: displayName, facebook, faculty, friend, id, major, n_id, name, page, password, picture, reporter, year_in_school", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"D:\\Study\\SeniorProject\\Code\\mysite\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 202, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"D:\\Study\\SeniorProject\\Code\\mysite\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 441, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"D:\\Study\\SeniorProject\\Code\\mysite\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 474, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"D:\\Study\\SeniorProject\\Code\\mysite\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1127, in get_list\n    objects = self.obj_get_list(request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"D:\\Study\\SeniorProject\\Code\\mysite\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1890, in obj_get_list\n    base_object_list = self.apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)\n\n  File \"D:\\Study\\SeniorProject\\Code\\mysite\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1862, in apply_filters\n    return self.get_object_list(request).filter(**applicable_filters)\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py\", line 624, in filter\n    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py\", line 642, in _filter_or_exclude\n    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\query.py\", line 1250, in add_q\n    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\query.py\", line 1122, in add_filter\n    process_extras=process_extras)\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\query.py\", line 1316, in setup_joins\n    \"Choices are: %s\" % (name, \", \".join(names)))\n\nFieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'page_set' into field. Choices are: displayName, facebook, faculty, friend, id, major, n_id, name, page, password, picture, reporter, year_in_school\n"}
```

Comment: can anyone explain this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have also been struggling with the same FieldError thrown from setup_joins, and I think I just solved my issue. I was trying to filter through a Many-to-Many relationship, and could never get the "_set" in `fields.ToManyField()` to work. After debugging the TastyPie code in the error case and in a working simple filter, I realized it may be possible to bypass the need for the intermediary resource altogether.

Here is what worked for me, I hope it helps in your situation. Since I don't know your model setup, I'll make up a similar example.

First, the models:

```
### models.py ###
from django.db import models

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe')
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient')
    weight = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.recipe, self.ingredient)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='RecipeIngredient')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

And here are the ModelResources:

```
### api.py ###
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from tastypie import fields
from some_app.models import Ingredient, Recipe

class IngredientResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'ingredient'
        filtering = {
            'name': ALL,
        }

class RecipeResource(ModelResource):
    ingredients = fields.ToManyField(
        'some_app.api.IngredientResource',
        'ingredients',
        full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'recipe'
        filtering = {
            'title': ALL,
            'ingredients': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

Notice I do not have a RecipeIngredientResource, I hook directly to the IngredientResource, which works because the Recipe model includes the ManyToManyField `ingredients` with the option `through='RecipeIngredient'`

An example URL to filter all recipes for a particular ingredient then looks like:

`http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/recipe/?ingredients__name=blueberry`

And, for completeness, here's a fixture for a Django app named 'some_app' to save time entering data for anyone wanting to implement this example:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "some_app.ingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "apple", 
            "description": "a tempting fruit"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "some_app.ingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "cherry", 
            "description": "a red fruit"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 3, 
        "model": "some_app.ingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "blueberry", 
            "description": "a blue fruit"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 4, 
        "model": "some_app.ingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "flour", 
            "description": "used for baking and stuff"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 5, 
        "model": "some_app.ingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "sugar", 
            "description": "makes stuff sweet"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 1, 
            "weight": 3, 
            "ingredient": 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 1, 
            "weight": 2, 
            "ingredient": 4
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 3, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 1, 
            "weight": 4, 
            "ingredient": 5
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 4, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 2, 
            "weight": 8, 
            "ingredient": 2
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 5, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 2, 
            "weight": 4, 
            "ingredient": 4
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 6, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 2, 
            "weight": 6, 
            "ingredient": 5
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 7, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 3, 
            "weight": 15, 
            "ingredient": 3
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 8, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 3, 
            "weight": 5, 
            "ingredient": 4
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 9, 
        "model": "some_app.recipeingredient", 
        "fields": {
            "recipe": 3, 
            "weight": 6, 
            "ingredient": 5
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "some_app.recipe", 
        "fields": {
            "title": "Apple Pie"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "some_app.recipe", 
        "fields": {
            "title": "Cherry Pie"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "pk": 3, 
        "model": "some_app.recipe", 
        "fields": {
            "title": "Blueberry Pie"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I have an almost identical model (without the m2m through model) and i ran into trouble with integrity constraints as well. Using your example, are you able to post (and more importantly patch) different receipts with the same ingredient without getting a constraint violation ?

Comment: @haki I ran into numerous issues with TastyPie, as my models are highly nested (hierarchical) with many validation considerations. I moved to the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and never looked back. I'm not knocking TastyPie, but DRF just seemed more intuitive to me, and I have never found any complex situation I couldn't solve by overriding API view methods.

Answer (score -1):

This is the thing, if `django tastypie` works very similar to django (as anyone could expect) you are using a bad keyword, in you case, It wouldn't be `page_set`, use just `page` instead and it will work.

I recommend to you using a plural in the field name

```
pages = fields.ToManyField('chula.api.PageResource','page_set',null=True)
```

so the forward relation is `pages` and the backward relation is `page_set` I cant remember which now. But anyway it will look nicer.

Comment: I change "page = fields.ToManyField('chula.api.PageResource','page_set',null=True)" to "pages = fields.ToManyField('chula.api.PageResource','page_set',null=True)"
as you told me but it still has the same error.when I request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/nisit/?format=json&pages__id=1"

Comment: may be the filtering meta option in the NisitResource, `'page' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,` to `'pages' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,` and make sure that meta class is correctly indented.

Comment: "so the forward relation is pages and the backward relation is page_set" can you elaborate this statement,I don't understand it. Thank you very much Oscar David Arbelaez for all of your answers

Comment: http://46424.com/question/24238#.UQ3e2h000Wk He got the same problem. But no one come to answer him.